# Contact Form Setup PHPMailer

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer, contact-form

I'm trying to get my contact form to work but since I don't have and IDE with a debugger I can't figure out where the PHP code fails.
Also, instead of a success message that replaces the message box and submit button which I think it's doing now, I would like to redirect to thank-you.html
Would appreciate some pointers.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-left small-screen-center os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInRight" data-os-animation-delay="0.3s">
            <form id="contactForm" class="contact-form">
              <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name *" type="text" required/>
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </div>
              <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email *" type="email" required>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </div>
              <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Your number " type="number">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> </div>
              <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Your company " type="text">
                <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> </div>
              <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject " type="text">
                <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> </div>
              <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message *" rows="5" required></textarea>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </div>
              <div>
                <input type="submit" value="send message" class="btn btn-link">
              </div>
            </form>
            <div id="messages" style="padding-top:10px;"></div>
          </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
// Setting up PHPMailer
$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
// Visit http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tip_srvrs for more info on server settings
// For GMail    => smtp.gmail.com
//     Hotmail  => smtp.live.com
//     Yahoo    => smtp.mail.yahoo.com
//     Lycos    => smtp.mail.lycos.com
//     AOL      => smtp.aol.com
$mail->Host = 'secure.emailsrvr.com';                       // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
//This is the email that you need to set so PHPMailer will send the email from
$mail->Username = 'my@emailadress.com';             // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'XXXXXX';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
// Add the address to send the mail to
$mail->AddAddress('my@emailadress.com');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

// add your company name here
$company_name = 'My Company';

// choose which fields you would like to be validated separated by |
// options required - check input has content valid_email - check for valid email
$field_rules = array(
    'name' => 'required',
    'email'   => 'required|valid_email',
    'message' => 'required'
);

// change your error messages here
$error_messages = array(
    'required'    => 'This field is required',
    'valid_email' => 'Please enter a valid email address'
);

// select where each inputs error messages will be shown
$error_placements = array(
    'name'         => 'top',
    'email'        => 'top',
    'subject'      => 'right',
    'message'      => 'right',
    'submitButton' => 'right'
);

// success message
$success_message            = new stdClass();
$success_message->message   = 'Thanks! your message has been sent';
$success_message->field     = 'submitButton';
$success_message->placement = $error_placements['submitButton'];

// mail failure message
$mail_error_message            = new stdClass();
$mail_error_message->message   = 'Sorry your mail was not sent - please try again later';
$mail_error_message->field     = 'submitButton';
$mail_error_message->placement = $error_placements['submitButton'];

// DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE UNLESS YOU KNOW YOUR STUFF!

$fields = $_POST;

$returnVal           = new stdClass();
$returnVal->status   = 'error';
$returnVal->messages = array();

if (!empty($fields)) {
    //Validate each of the fields
    foreach ($field_rules as $field => $rules) {
        $rules = explode('|', $rules);

        foreach ($rules as $rule) {
            $result = null;

            if (isset($fields[$field])) {
                if (!empty($rule)) {
                    $result = $rule($fields[$field]);
                }

                if ($result === false) {
                    $error = new stdClass();
                    $error->field = $field;
                    $error->message = $error_messages[$rule];
                    $error->placement = $error_placements[$field];

                    $returnVal->messages[] = $error;
                    // break from the rule loop so we only get 1 error at a time
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                $returnVal->messages[] =  $field . ' ' . $error_messages['required'];
            }
        }
    }

    if (empty($returnVal->messages)) {                         // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
        $email = stripslashes(safe($fields['email']));
        $body = stripslashes(safe($fields['message']));
        // The sender of the form/mail
        $mail->From = $email;
        $mail->FromName = stripslashes(safe($fields['name']));
        $mail->Subject = '[' . $company_name . ']';
        $content = $email . " sent you a message from your contact form:<br><br>";
        $content .= "-------<br>" . $body . "<br><br><br><br>Email: " . $email;
        $mail->Body = $content;

        if(@$mail->Send()) {
            $returnVal->messages[] = $success_message;
            $returnVal->status = 'ok';
        } else {
            $returnVal->messages[] = $mail_error_message;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($returnVal);
}

function required($str, $val = false)
{
    if (!is_array($str)) {
        $str = trim($str);
        return ($str == '') ? false : true;
    } else {
        return !empty($str);
    }
}

function valid_email($str)
{
    return (!preg_match("/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD", $str)) ? false : true;
}

function safe($name)
{
    return(str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", '%0a', '%0d', 'Content-Type:', 'bcc:','to:','cc:'), '', $name));
}
```

Oh, one more thing: This contact form came with a website template and within the contact.js I found this warning:
Usage Note:
    -----------
    Do not use both ajaxSubmit and ajaxForm on the same form.  These
    functions are mutually exclusive.  Use ajaxSubmit if you want
    to bind your own submit handler to the form.

What does that mean exactly? The contact.js contains code for both. Do I need to delete some of it to get it to work?

[Here is the jsfiddle for the contact.js](http://jsfiddle.net/lschoebel/ce3pz84q/)

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your PHP code ?

Comment: I'm editing the template in dreamweaver. The program doesn't give me an error, however when I click the submit button on the live test site nothing happens.

Comment: `since I don't have and IDE with a debugger I can't figure out where the PHP code fails` But you can download an IDE right?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. That's how you check for errors.

Comment: Error reporting has nothing to do with dreamweaver. You can always manually add it to the top of your php file: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);`.

Comment: okay I will do that now. In the meantime, do you guys see anything that jumps out at you off the bat? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You have way too much code for that. Sorry.

Comment: hard to say; you've named attributes for your inputs but I don't see any form tags, method etc.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem when using templates. Sorry about all the code. I'm just not that great with PHP or JS so I'm not exactly sure what is necessary and what is not. Also: I added the code you said to add but nothing is being reported.